# Novel idea for NoSQL node mapping based on time based ids?

Tags: database, nosql, distributed

I'm coding a new NoSQL database, and had what I thought was a novel idea (for me anyways) regarding the hashing mechanism used to locate nodes for a given key.

I'm using object keys that incorporate a timestamp. A hash will be used to determine the node(s) holding the data.  Pretty common so far.

The (possible) twist lies in that a map will record the times at which nodes have been added to the cluster.  That way I can determine for any given object which nodes were present in the cluster when that object was added (and therefore which nodes hold the object's data).

I'm thinking that in this way growing the cluster wont require any data to be transferred.  Objects always live on the same node...for ever.

Has anyone tried something like this?  Any potential problems that anyone can foresee?

Comment: Crashing nodes? Replication?

Comment: Time synchronisation between servers in an enterprise/on a cloud is a big problem, as is resolution -- processors are /really/ fast!

Comment: @jgauffin, I can see that replication of a lost node wont be too efficient.  Looks like it would require me to traverse all objects on all nodes to see which ones belong on it.  I may need to rethink this.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, time synchronization shouldn't matter too much (as far as I can see).  When object keys are created the number of the node that created the id and a number indicating how many objects the server has created is included as well.  That way I don't have to worry about the collisions on time.